# How can I set my document in Illustrator to 700dpi?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, dpi, creative-cloud

I am using Illustrator CC and I need to create a large image document `85cm X 200cm`, but the printing guy is asking me this document to be in `700dpi`. **How can I set, emulate or create this within Illustrator?** Illustrator only allows me to create `72dpi`, `150dpi, or  300dpi`.

Comment: Yes, 700 dots per inch.

Comment: It can not be DPI.. it must be PPI. DPI is on the *printed page* and has nothing to do with working on a monitor. PPI is the pixel resolution on screen. Even though your "printing guy" may have mentioned "dpi" he most likely meant "ppi".

Comment: All this numbers has no sense. I´m sure the information is incomplete. No sisyem in comercial printing I am aware of uses 700ppi. The image 85x200 cm is verey big, 700ppi is insane. Probably the "printing guy" has to ask the correct information. Asking for dpi units to the client's file has no sense either.

Comment: @Metis, and then to add to the fun, today, with high resolution monitors now relatively common, "pixels" on screen aren't even a single item; see "logical pixel vs. physical pixel."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

85cm x 200cm is 33.4646in x 78.7402in. To set it at 700ppi (pixels per inch) you need to multiply that by 700, so your document should be: 23425px x 55118px, independent of whatever ppi you choose in Illustrator.

That is a LOT of pixels, particularly because illustrator outputs a vector file that is 100% scalable (unless you are using raster images within). 700ppi is overkill for a sign of that dimensions imho, you could easily get away with 150ppi, or even 70ppi.

Regardless, you may be better creating your file at 1/10 scale - 70ppi is a much more manageable 2343px x 5512px.

Comment: PPI and DPI are 2 different things. Here is some reference that should help explain: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/what-dpi-should-i-resize-my-image-to-for-best-printing-quality

Answer (score 5):

John answered if you are concerned about raster images within Illustrator.

However, I wanted to point out that Illustrator - being a vector based application - is **resolution independent**. This means there is no ppi/dpi setting. Vector content has no ppi/dpi it scales infinitely without issue. PPI/DPI is for raster-based images where scaling can vastly alter the quality of the image.

If I were given those specifications and I was working in Illustrator I'd simply set the **Document Raster Effects Settings (DRES)** found in the **Effects Menu** to 700, then ignore PPI/DPI for all content created in Illustrator. DRES controls the PPI of any raster *effects created within Illustrator* (drop shadows, glows, etc). It does not alter placed raster images. If you are placing raster images within Illustrator, *then* you need to ensure those raster images are set to 700ppi in a raster editing application such as Photoshop. You can't alter a raster image's native ppi from within Illustrator.

In short, you don't need to worry about ppi with Illustrator. That's the entire point of vector content.

Answer (score 3):

Most large format inkjet printers have a 700 dpi setting. This is usually a medium to high quality printer setting (depending on the printer).

Usually solvent inkjet printers have a lot of noise (printer and material dependent) so 700 ppi is absolutely an overkill.

For a regular banner print 200 dpi is enough, you won't notice the difference.

Higher quality materials and printers are capable of printing fine details, but I doubt that more than 300 dpi is ever necessary. (In large format printing)

The printer guy is confused. He doesn't know the difference between 700 dpi and 700 ppi.

On 3 different large format printer I worked on, the usual 3 settings for print quality were about 300dpi, (low) 700 dpi (medium) and 1400 (high) (some materials are not even profiled for larger dpi than 700, because that would be just a waste of time and resources.) (The printer RIP software does the scaling and calculation so feeding the printer with graphics ranging from 70ppi to 300 ppi is generally enough)

Answer (score -1):

Besides above answers, you usually need to deliver your artwork to the printing guy in TIFF format. So during exporting your artwork to TIFF, in resolution box, select "Other" then set the resolution to 700 PPI.

Comment: This only depends on the printer and also doesn't answer the question.